# Download project from URL

Tags: version-control, download, mercurial

I was looking for downloading the example projects codes here: [andengine](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/#hg)

The question is: How can i download the folder hg to get the example projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download `mercurial` (or TortoiseHG client) [from here](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/download/index.html) and execute in command line:

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/
```